# Is there an equivalent of to_yaml_properties for inspect in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, inspect

`Object#to_yaml_properties` is a method you can use to list which instance variables you want serialized to YAML without having to re-implement the entire serialization process. If you want to exclude certain instance variables, you could use `super` and then filter out the ones you don't want.

Is there an equivalent method that allows you to only list certain variables when calling `Object#inspect`, or would I have to re-implement the entire method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such mechanism in vanilla Ruby.

On the plus side, you could implement it and then use it in your redefinition of `MyClass#inspect`. You don't have to do all the work per class, just create a class-level method that allows you to set the inspect.

Or you could add your own `Object#limited_inspect` and redefine `Kernel#p` (or add your own shortcut) to use all instance variables minus whatever ones might be excluded.